# Grouping hashes by a key value while merging the other key values into a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I've seen a lot of similar questions around, but this is a very specific case.

What I have as input:

```
entries = [
   {:action=>"X", :sequence=>1},
   {:action=>"Y", :sequence=>2},
   {:action=>"W", :sequence=>2},
   {:action=>"Z", :sequence=>3}
]
```

What I want as output (join actions by sequence with "and" and all actions with ", "):

`"X, Y and W, Z"`

How I've done it:

```
group = entries.group_by {|x| x.delete(:sequence)}.values
=> [[{:action=>"X"}], [{:action=>"Y"}, {:action=>"W"}], [{:action=>"Z"}]]

array = group.map { |el| el.map { |h| h[:action] } }
=> [["X"], ["Y", "W"], ["Z"]]

string = array.map { |a| a.join(' and ') }.join(', ')
=> "X, Y and W, Z"
```

It works, but its far from being clean. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: How are 'Y' and 'W' differentiated (both sequence 2)? It looks like in your output they're affiliated with 'X' and 'Z' respectively, but could the two be swapped in the output?

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Fixed, its "X, Y and W, Z".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below is the shortest one I can think of:

```
entries.group_by { |e| e.delete :sequence }
       .values
       .map { |e| e.map(&:values).join ' and ' }
       .join ', '
```

Another one [non-destructive]:

```
entries.map(&:values)
       .group_by(&:last)
       .values
       .map { |e| e.map(&:first).join ' and ' }
       .join ', '
```

And even:

```
 entries.map(&:values)
        .group_by(&:pop)
        .values
        .map { |e| e.join ' and ' }
        .join ', '
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may play with `each_with_object` method:

```
entries.each_with_object(Hash.new {[]}) do |e, m|
  m[e[:sequence]] <<= e[:action]
end.values
   .map{|e| e.join(' and ')}
   .join(", ")
#=> "X, Y and W, Z"
```